# Manera de usar literals y otras mejoras de ES6 y precompilarlos en rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, es6

¿Saben si hay algún soporte para precompilar javascripts usando literals y otras mejoras de ES6?

Quería empezar a usar en proyectos **rails ES6** pero al precompilar en producción me falla.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por ahora rails no tiene un soporte oficial para ES6, sin embargo hay algunas gemas que podrían ayudarte:

#### rails 4.x

- https://github.com/rmacklin/sprockets-bumble_d (en conjunto con Sprockets 3).

#### rails 5.x:

- https://github.com/es6-rails/es6-rails/blob/master/README.md
- https://github.com/fnando/babel-schmooze-sprockets o https://github.com/babel/ruby-babel-transpiler (en conjunto con Sprockets 4).
- https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6/blob/master/README.md (en conjunto con Sprockets 3).

Comment: Gracias Gerry. Aún no lo probé pero veo que me va a servir. Gracias